# storm kill topology-name [-w wait-time-secs]

Tags: apache-storm

I want to kill topology with wait-time-secs =1 sec

```
storm kill topology-name [-w 1]
```

Is this syntax is correct?
otherwise ,how to use -w flag?
Give any example to kill storm topology with wait-time-secs ?

Answer (score 1):

```
storm kill topology-name -w 1
```

just use it this way